# How to generate all the combinations of the elements from an array in order?

Tags: python

I want to get all the combinations of an array's element in the following order.
say: `a = [2, 3, 5]`, then after I call `mysterious(a)`, I should get another array that is: `[2, 3, 5, 2 * 3, 2 * 5, 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 5]` or `[2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]`. Note: must be directly in this order.

To make my question more clear:

1. when `lst = [2, 3, 5, 7]`, the return `lst` should be `[2, 3, 5, 7, 2 * 3, 2 * 5, 2 * 7, 3 * 5, 3 * 7, 5 * 7, 2 * 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 7, 2 * 5 * 7, 3 * 5 * 7, 2 * 3 * 5 * 7]` or `[2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 10, 14, 15, 21, 35, 30, 42, 70, 105, 210]`
2. you can think of the `returnList` is in the order of (nCr n chooses r) nC1, nC2, ..., nCn.
3. I am asking for a generic answer, you should handle arbitrary length of input list.

I can apply a recursion algorithm to derive all the combinations, but due to how recursion works, I can only get `[2, 3, 2 * 3, 5, 2 * 5, 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 5] or [2, 3, 6, 5, 10, 15, 30]`, which is in a wrong order.
See my code below:

```
def listBuilding(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    if len(lst) == 2:
        return [lst[0], lst[1], lst[0] * lst[1]]
    else:
        previous = listBuilding(lst[:(length - 1)])
        return previous + [lst[length - 1]] + [(lst[length - 1] * x) for x in previous]
```

Can someone help me? I think this should be a common problem, and someone might have answered this before, but I cannot find it.
I am expecting an easy answer.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use recursion? And do you not want to just sort the list at the end?

Comment: I think the answer posted by @U9-Forward is correct and simple.

Comment: @NiranjhanaNarayanan my recursion above is wrong because it doesn't give me the correct order I mentioned in my post. I don't want to sort it at the end, that's the reason I am asking here for a specific order.

Comment: Ah okay. That's great, go ahead and mark that answer as correct by checking the tick mark next to it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use `functools.reduce` and `itertools.combinations` and `operator.mul` with a nested `for` loop which does it, also add `a` and `l` at the end:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> import operator
>>> a = [2, 3, 5]
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(2, len(a) + 1):
    for x in combinations(a, i):
        l.append(reduce(operator.mul, x, 1))


>>> a + l
[2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]
>>>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it will not be in order if any product of small elements are smaller than a single element.  i.e. a = [2,3,7] yields: [2, 3, 7, 6, 14, 21, 42]